# Multivariate chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am applying the steepest descent algorithm with an exact line search for a particular choice of $f$. If $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf p$ are fixed vectors, and I define $g \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ by $g(\alpha) = f(\mathbf x + \alpha \mathbf p)$, is it true that $g'(\alpha) = \nabla f(\mathbf x + \alpha \mathbf p)^T\mathbf p$? I'm not sure what else it could be, and this resembles the univariate case the most.

Comment: I suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. And $C^1$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Generally for a composition $g = f\circ h$ it holds that $[Jg](x) = [Jf]\big(h(x)\big) \cdot [Jh](x)$, where $Jf$ is the Jacobian of $f$, and $[Jf](x)$ is the Jacobian of $f$ evaluated at $x$. This is simply the chain rule.

In your case $g$ is a function of a single variable and thus its Jacobian is simply the usual derivative. We have $g = f \circ h$ where $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $h: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $h(\alpha) = \mathbf x + \alpha \mathbf p$.

Hence, $Jf$ is the usual gradient as a row vector ($1 \times n$) and $Jh$ is a $n\times 1$, column vector. Notice that, as needs be, their product is $1\times 1$, essentially a scalar.

Now, since $h$ is really simple, we can calculate $Jh$ explicitly. We have that:

$$h(\alpha) = (x_1 + \alpha p_1, x_2+\alpha p_2, \dots, x_n + \alpha p_n)$$

where $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and $p=(p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n)$. Hence, $h'(\alpha) = \mathbf p$.